# How to prevent ssh connection from timing out?

Tags: tcp, paramiko

I got a problem with ssh connection.

I executed commands on a remote Linux server via python `paramiko`. The command executed for a long time(more than 40 minutes) and then returned the message which I want to check, there was no message returned during the executing.

I have tried different ways:

1. The ssh connection fails before the result returns if I don't change the `sshd` config on the remote server.
2. Enabled `TCPKeepAlive`/`ClientAliveInterval`/`ClientAliveCountMax` on the remote server, the server sent messages to the client during the idle period cyclically, the message was `unhandled keepalive request.....`. It prevents the connection from timing out, but in this way, I can't get the message returned by the command.

Help me, thank you!